# Are duplicated private member variables preferable to a shared protected member?

Tags: c#, coding-style

This is an idiom I have noticed in a C# codebase which I have been working on recently:

```
class Base
{
   private readonly MemberClass _memberVariable;

   public Base(MemberClass memberValue)
   {
       _memberVariable = memberValue;
   }

   // methods accessing memberVariable...
}

class Derived : Base
{
   private readonly MemberClass _memberVariable;

   public Derived(MemberClass memberValue) : base(memberValue)
   {
       _memberVariable = memberValue;
   }

   // methods accessing memberVariable...
}
```

Both the base class and its derived class have a member variable which is intialised in their respective constructors, but instead of declaring the member as `protected` in the base class and having it available in its subclasses, each subclass has its own `private` copy of the member.

My first reaction to this was that it was an unnecessary duplication. On thinking about it some more, I feel that the duplication might be justified as it reduces the amount of coupling between the base and derived classes and prevents a change in the base class causing inadvertent breakage in its subclasses.

Are `protected` members "considered harmful" in C#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would consider protected *fields* harmful - and I would also consider the data duplication harmful, if the values should always be the same. However, the base class could expose the private field's value via a property instead:

```
class Base
{
   private readonly MemberClass memberVariable;

   protected MemberClass MemberProperty { get { return memberVariable; } }    

   public Base(MemberClass memberValue)
   {
       this.memberVariable = memberValue;
   }

   // methods accessing memberVariable or MemberProperty...
}

class Derived : Base
{
   public Derived(MemberClass memberValue) : base(memberValue)
   {
   }

   // methods accessing MemberProperty...
}
```

In C# 6, the base class becomes simpler:

```
class Base
{
   protected MemberClass MemberProperty { get; }    

   public Base(MemberClass memberValue)
   {
       this.MemberProperty = memberValue;
   }

   // methods accessing MemberProperty...
}
```

That's still a protected property backed by a private readonly field - it's just the compiler does all the boilerplate for you.

Comment: `protected` *does* feel like a bit of a hold-over from the early 90s when "reuse" was heavily promoted as a reason for moving to an object-oriented language...

Answer (score 1):

> Are protected members "considered harmful" in C#?

Members in general? No, for sure. There are lots of good reasons to have `protected` members in C# code.

Furthermore, I think that clearly the code you've used in your example is broken. Having two copies of the exact same value all the time is wasteful and if anything, is likely to create bugs (as soon as you have two fields that are supposed to have the same value, you now have the opportunity for those values to be not the same and thus wind up breaking some code somewhere).

As far as the question of `protected` *fields* specifically? I will dissent from Jon's opinion here, at least to a degree: for a `readonly` field, IMHO it is perfectly fine in some situations.

The main reason for encapsulating such a field in a property would be so that the implementation could be elaborated on later without having to recompile dependent code (assuming that code is in a different assembly).

But IMHO such a field is very likely to *never* need elaboration on its implementation. Such fields are usually intended as sources for constant value. A getter with something more elaborate than just returning a field value is, while not exactly rare, not all that usual either (the biggest exception I can think of being lazily-initialized values).

For now, most of us are using C# 5 or earlier, and that's likely to be true for some time now. Until the C# 6 syntax is available widely, I'd say that using a `readonly protected` field is a fine concession to conciseness without a major maintenance/correctness hazard *in certain specific scenarios*.

Naturally, the more complicated the code gets, the more useful good, safe abstractions will be, and the more likely you should stick with a truly encapsulated read-only property.

But as an absolute rule? No, I don't think it's necessary to have a blanket prohibition against `readonly protected` fields.

Comment: Out of interest - and I really am genuinely interested here - does that apply to public fields as well? If not, what's the real difference? While there are likely to be fewer subclasses, they *could* be anywhere - unless you have an internal abstract method for example. Does it make a difference to you whether this is a corporate codebase or open source? I would certainly feel less bad about a protected field than a public field, but I can't pin down an objective reason why... it only takes one subclass you can't control to make it a compatibility issue :(

Comment: @Jon: Does what apply to public fields? My tolerance for them? Yes...I do not have an absolute rule against public fields **as long as they are `readonly`**. I will never have writeable public fields (frankly, even in demo code I follow this rule), but for simple set-once values, sure. I am fine with `public`, especially for very simple classes. In general: if the class's sole purpose is to hold values, I allow `public readonly`, otherwise I don't. I do look forward to C# 6 when there will no longer be even the slightest verbosity advantage over using properties.

Comment: @Jon: note that for your specific question about "corporate codebase" (lots of experience with) and "open source" (zero personal experience with), I am more likely to seal the class in that case, eliminating the question of subclasses initializing the field differently. If I can't seal the class, then I am more likely to keep the field private and require subclasses to pass initialization values through the constructor, if they are to be allowed to provide them at all. So yes, context certainly matters.

Comment: The duplicated member name on the base and derived class was actually the first thing that caught my attention